# How to write this probability in a paper?

Tags: probability, proof-writing, publishing

I would like to know how to write the following probability in a scientific way:

$S=P(x_{1}<y, x_{2}<y,..., x_{n}<y, x_{1}>0, x_{2}>0,..., x_{n}>0)$

Can I use matrix notation for proper representing these multiple conditions such that:

$S=P(X<y, X>0)$

where $ X=[x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}]$

Comment: I would write it as $Pr(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n X_i)$ where $X_i$ is the event $0<x_i<y$.

Comment: The one confusing thing about $X<y$ is that it's not so clear that $y$ is a scalar. Otherwise that is fine.

Comment: How about $\Pr(\max(X_i) \lt y, \min(X_i) \gt 0)$?

Comment: Indeed, if $X=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, then the probability you want is $\mathsf P(0<\min X, \max X< y)$